# React-Bootstraps Validation States and Form Submission validation

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation

I'm attempting to use react-bootstraps FormControls and was following this article to get started: https://react-bootstrap-v3.netlify.app/components/forms/?#forms-validation

Below is my current code, as can be seen, the FormGroup is inside a modals body and there is a separate button in the footer to submit the form. As i type inputs into the text box, handleChange and validateName are invoked correctly and the UI changes colors accordingly, but I'm still able to submit the form regardless of the validation state.

**The Form**

```
           <UIModal
                show={this.state.showModal}
                onHide={this.handleCloseModal}
                ariaLabelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
                modalHeader="MyModal"
                modalBody={
                    <form>
                        <FormGroup controlId="formBasicText" validationState={this.validateName()}>
                            <ControlLabel>Name</ControlLabel>
                            <FormControl name="name" type="text" value={this.state.name} placeholder="Name" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                            <FormControl.Feedback/>
                            <HelpBlock>{this.state.errors.name}</HelpBlock>
                        </FormGroup>
                    </form>
                }
                modalFooter = {
                    <ButtonToolbar>
                        <UIButton type="submit" bsStyle="primary" bsSize="small" buttonValue="Save"
                            onClick={this.handleFormSubmit}
                        />
                        <UIButton type="submit" bsStyle="default" bsSize="small"  buttonValue="Cancel"
                            onClick={this.handleCloseModal}
                        />
                    </ButtonToolbar>
                }
            />
```

**handleChange**

```
handleChange(event) {
    const {name, value} = event.target;
    let state = this.state;
    state[name] = value;
    this.setState(state);
}
```

**validateName**

```
 validateName() {
    const length = this.state.name.length;

    if (length === 0) {
        return 'error';
    } else {
        return 'success';
    }
 }
```

**handleFormSubmit**

```
handleFormSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    const formData = this.state;

    // do some validation here
 }
```

I'm confused on how this type of thing is normally handled with react-bootstrap, the validateName method is great to update the style of the UI but it doesn't seem to be able to connect to the state at all, would I need to essentially re-validate everything again in handleFormSubmit, or is there some kind of reference to the validation errors that i could reference as part of my final validation?

Comment: I recommend you to use react-formik library. It is really cool. You can do bunch of things with it.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd be able to since its a licensed product is it not?

Comment: I also don't think thats my best option cause I'm dealing with class components instead function components